# Save and Load Random Number Generator State in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, std, mt19937

This question has been asked before ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361050/saving-random-number-generator-state-in-c11)) but the (accepted) answer is not satisfactory.

The following example saves and loads the state but depending on the number of generated values it works or it doesn't:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  const int preN = 4;
  const int middleN = 0;

  // initialize randGen
  std::mt19937 randGen1;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution1;


  // print some initial random numbers
  for (int i=0;i<preN;++i)
    std::cout << distribution1(randGen1)<<" ";

  // save state
  std::cout << std::endl << "Saving...\n";
  {
    std::ofstream fout("seed.dat");
    fout << randGen1;
  }

  // maybe advance randGen1
  for (int i=0;i<middleN;++i)
    std::cout << distribution1(randGen1)<<" ";

  // load saved state into randGen2 
  std::cout << std::endl << "Loading...\n";
  std::ifstream fin("seed.dat");
  std::mt19937 randGen2;
  fin >> randGen2;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution2;

  // are both randGen equal?
  assert(randGen1 == randGen2);

  // print numbers from both generators
  std::cout << "Generator1\tGenerator2\n";
  std::cout << distribution1(randGen1) << "\t"
            << distribution2(randGen2) << "\n";

  return 0;

}
```

With these parameters it works like expected. However, if I set `preN=3` the output looks like:

```
0.13453 -0.146382 0.46065 
Saving...

Loading...
Generator1  Generator2
-1.87138    0.163712
```

Why did the assert not apply? Now I set `preN=3` and `middleN=1` and the output is

```
0.13453 -0.146382 0.46065 
Saving...
-1.87138 
Loading...
Generator1  Generator2
0.163712    0.163712
```

If I set `middleN` to anything larger than 1 the assert applies.
Can anyone explain what is going on? What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Tested with GCC5.4.0 and CLANG3.8.0 on Linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not your random number generator's state. The problem is your *distribution's* state. Yes, distributions can have state too.

You can get the same values by resetting the normal distribution's state with `reset`. Alternatively, you can [preserve and reconstitute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/operator_ltltgtgt) the distribution's state too, using `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Tried it too (because that behaviour looked fascinating and i did not try C++ for a long time) and can say for sure, that a uniform-dist behaves differently!

Comment: @sascha: I'm not sure what you mean that it behaves differently.

Comment: That it probably does not have an internal-state which matters (much simpler than normal-dist), but that's just empirical observation. It was just my first trial. Maybe it does too. Ignore my comment. Nice answer!

Comment: @sascha: Whether a distribution has state that affects its output is implementation dependent.

Comment: You got any idea on the why of this kind of free specification? I can't think of any good reason not to assume these are state-less except for caching (build a random-pool). I also don't think that scipy does that (at first look even GSL).

Comment: `normal_distribution` may or may not have state. It all depends on the implementation's choice of algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much. I considered this to be the case and something made me think to circumvent the problem by introducing `distribution2`. In any case, I'll mark the answer as the solution but add the corrected code below.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answer from [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) above, I can add the corrected code below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  const int preN = 7;
  const int middleN = 0;

  // initialize another randGen
  std::mt19937 randGen1;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution1;

  // print some initial random numbers
  for (int i=0;i<preN;++i)
    std::cout << distribution1(randGen1)<<" ";

  // save state
  std::cout << std::endl << "Saving...\n";
  {
    std::ofstream fout("seed.dat");
    fout << randGen1;
    fout.close();
    std::ofstream fout2("distribution.dat");
    fout2 << distribution1;
    fout2.close();
  }

  // maybe advance randGen
  for (int i=0;i<middleN;++i)
    std::cout << distribution1(randGen1)<<" ";

  // load saved state into randGen2
  std::cout << std::endl << "Loading...\n";
  std::mt19937 randGen2;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution2;
  {
    std::ifstream fin("seed.dat");
    fin >> randGen2;
    fin.close();
    std::ifstream fin2("distribution.dat");
    fin2 >> distribution2;
    fin2.close();
  }

  // are both randGen equal?
  assert(randGen1 == randGen2);
  assert(distribution1 == distribution2);

  // print numbers from both generators
  std::cout << "Generator1\tGenerator2\n";
  std::cout << distribution1(randGen1) << "\t"
            << distribution2(randGen2) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how one can save and restore seed forrandom numbers of double float precision. It should be similar for integers - use jrand48 instead of erand48.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

     unsigned short savedseed[3];
     unsigned short currentseed[3];
     double x;

     /*-- initialize ramdom seed to whatever --*/
     currentseed[0]= 23;
     currentseed[1]= 45;
     currentseed[2]= 67;

     printf("\n");

     /*-- generate three random numbers  --*/
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     printf("\n");

     /*-- save seed  --*/
     memcpy(savedseed, currentseed, 3*sizeof(unsigned short));

     /*-- generate next three random numbers  --*/     
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     printf("\n", x);

     /*-- restore seed  --*/
     memcpy(currentseed, savedseed,  3*sizeof(unsigned short));

     /*-- generate the same three random numbers again --*/
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     x =  erand48(currentseed);     printf("%g\n", x);
     printf("\n");  
}
```